# UIImageView won't load image in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I'm new to UICollectionViews. I have setup a basic UICollectionViewController with rows of 2 cells. In the controller I have one cell and I dragged a UIImageView into it. I connected it to the custom cell class. I made sure so change the class of the cell to this one in the interface builder also. In my view controller I have this code:

```
@implementation StickersViewController

static NSString * const reuseIdentifier = @"stickerCell";

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];




    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];


    //Add the images
    self.images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"one.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"two.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"three.png"], nil];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDataSource>

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {

    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [self.images count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    StickerCell *cell = (StickerCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.imageView.image=self.images[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

I am getting this error when running the code: **UICollectionViewCell imageView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe8e0e7828**. Not sure why. Seems I have connected things up correctly. Could someone give me some pointers to where I might be going wrong please?

Comment: A knee-jerk reflex would be that your type casting isn't working right. Try checking that out, because instead of saying Sticker cell unrecognized selector.. it said UICollectionViewCell unrecognized selector sent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
```

where you're registering a `UICollectionViewCell` instead of your custom subclass. So that should be:

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[StickerCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
```

Also, keep in mind that in case that the setup is done in a Storyboard you do not need to register the class yourself since it is automatically handled for you (provided that you have set a custom class & a reuse identifier)

I hope that this makes sense

Answer (score 1):

refer this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12
 you will get the right answer.  probably i think you don't set the collection reusable view identifier
 select collection view cell goto attribute inspector and set the collection reusable view identifier = cell